# zpanel installation - reinstall mysql issue -CentOS-6.4 zpanel-10.1.0

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, centos

I have tried to install **zpanel 10.1.0 on centos 6.4** on own server machine.

The requirement was **fresh clean OS installation**.

Ref:[Here](http://docs.zpanelcp.com/?node=57)
But it is late for me since I already installed several pacages like LAMP stack,etc..

**ISSUE:**

As per the instructions I downloaded the installer script,Execute.
FYI:This script installs all the dependencies for the installation.

I already have mysql installed along with LAMP stack,With

```
$ mysql_secure_installation
```

This installer script tries to access the existing mysql.It fails since it generates its own  root password since it assumes this system is fresh install OS.

So I uninstalled all mysql related stuff's like mysql-server,libs.etc..But still it fails at same place.

**ErrorLog:**

> mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>
> error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

While Checking mysql from console I found that **mysql root password is the same that I set while Lamp stack installation** despite of several re installation.

This result in application without database access.

Looking for any advice here to get this solved.

Thanks.
Sorry for long post.

Comment: Dear all,

I found a (dirty) way to do that.

(here)[http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/completely-uninstall-mysql-server-759920/] and here](http://venakis.blogspot.in/2011/12/completely-wipeout-mysql-from-centos-to.html)

simply remove the mysql directory itself from ** /var/libs/mysql** after uninstalling your mysql packages.

 'rm -fR /var/libs/mysql'

then execute the installer as usual. 

My issue solved this way.
Thank you.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer...

Comment: Sorry!.i cant.I'm banned for spamming!.:(
(that was not my intention but am excited of having answer..did 3 posts.not irrelevant posts i solved,then only posted)

I dnt know how to raise reputations?.any help!

Comment: Ok; you can post one answer if you don't spam anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a (dirty) way to do that from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/completely-uninstall-mysql-server-759920/%5D) and [there](http://venakis.blogspot.in/2011/12/completely-wipeout-mysql-from-centos-to.html)

simply remove the mysql directory itself from **/var/libs/mysql** after uninstalling your mysql packages.

```
rm -fR /var/libs/mysql
```

then execute the installer as usual. My issue solved this way. Thank you.